# CSV Series is ambiguous Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to filter my csv file. I have 3 columns and the first one is `Espacio`.
I have an error with my sentence so I don't understand how can I do it because I ever filter my csv with this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('my.csv')
if df['Espacio'] == '*':

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: it works for numbers but not for str. @BradSolomon

Answer (score 1):

Basically when you do

```
df = pd.read_csv('my.csv')
```

The datatype of df is 'dataframe' so you can't directly index elements out of it. What you need to do is use iterrows method to loop over the rows and then index the element you need.

To test this I created a simple csv file as below

```
Espacio,b,c
*,2,3
4,5,6
```

And then used this code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('my.csv')

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Espacio'] == '*':
        print('here')
```

This should do what you need

Comment: `if row['Espacio'] == '*':` Can we use it instead of `if all (row['Espacio'] == '*')`:??

Comment: So you want to check if all the rows are ' * '?